# Move, Rename Flat File System to directories based on filename

Tags: linux, bash, sharding

I have a sun directory mounted on a centos system with 16000+ movs, the application that writes them there is now struggling to read the directory due to the amount of files.

Every filename is unique and delimited by a dash (-) if it does not have a dash it stays in the root.
For example.

Filenames 02342.mov, 1-9593-0002-001.mov, 1-9593-0002-002.mov, 2-3690-0005-001.mov, Y-0757-0245.mov and ROB-01-002-Y.mov should end up like this so that the client's web streaming application can stream it as it's original filename (their web team will handle that part).

```
mnt
|-- media
      |-- 02342.mov
      |-- 1
      |   |-- 9593
      |   |-- 0002
      |         |-- 001.mov
      |         |-- 002.mov
      |-- 2
      |   |-- 3690
      |         |-- 0005
      |               |-- 001.mov
      |-- ROB
      |   |-- 01
      |         |-- 002
      |               |-- Y.mov
      |-- Y
          |-- 0757
                |-- 0245.mov
```

However it creates the last part as a directory e.g. /mnt/media/1/9593/0002/001.mov/

Right my <strike>stolen</strike> script so far.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    for i in $(/bin/ls *-* | xargs)
    do
        dir=$(echo $i | cut -f1 -d '-')
        mkdir -p $dir
        dir1=$(echo $i | cut -f2 -d '-')
        mkdir -p $dir/$dir1
        dir2=$(echo $i | cut -f3 -d '-')
        mkdir -p $dir/$dir1/$dir2
        dir3=$(echo $i | cut -f4 -d '-') #here is where I get lost
        mkdir -p $dir/$dir1/$dir2/$dir3
        #dir4=$(echo $i | cut -f5 -d '-')
        #mkdir -p $dir/$dir1/$dir2/$dir3/$dir4
        echo $dir3
        #mv $i $dir3 # This doesnt work.

    done
```

I'm pretty sure just doing dir1, dir2 and so on is the wrong approach but my knowledge is limited at this point.

The last part I was going to do a simple regex rename afterwards but haven't got that far yet.

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call `ls`, `xargs`, or `cut`. Bash can handle it with path expansion and parameter expansion.

```
for mov in *-*.mov ; do
    path=${mov//-//}               # Replace all "-" with "/"
    path=${path%/*}                # Remove from the last "/"
    mkdir -p "$path"
    name=${mov##*-}                # Remove up to the last "-"
    mv "$mov" "$path/$name"
done
```

The glob might take very long and even fail. It might be better to use a tool that can read the files one by one without listing them all. See [Perl to the rescue: case study of deleting a large directory](http://blogs.perl.org/users/randal_l_schwartz/2011/03/perl-to-the-rescue-case-study-of-deleting-a-large-directory.html).

Comment: **still editing i keep hitting enter**

I ran this on a zero byte mirror and it worked flawlessly.  It's 5.4TB of data so I'l have to make a few GB copies and run some tests.

Now I need to work on URL rewriting so they still appear like they did.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I provide a pseudo algorithm first.

1. find all mov files using `find`
2. for each filename

   2.1 trim the file name path and its ending using bash substituions

   ```
    like `${filename##*/}` and `${filename%-*\.mov}`
   ```

   2.2 replace all dashes using bash's substitution builtins

   ```
    like `${filename//-/\/}`
   ```

   2.3 mkdir -p `${filename//-/\/}`

   2.4 move the file if needed

Hope this helps building a script.

Comment: Thanks, this helps for the learning process, unfortunately (for some) @choroba gave me the exact way to do it.